# Require authenticated user in asp.net core but require custom policy in some actions require custom policy

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization

My Asp.net core site required authentication by default

```
services.AddMvc(config =>
{
    //only allow authenticated users
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
    .Build();

    config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
```

but for one action I would need to allow anonymous access (/Account/AddUser if there are no users in the database).

I created this custom policy which checks that the user is either authenticated or that the user db is empty.

```
[Authorize(Policy = "NoUsersInDatabaseOrUserAuthenticated")]
public IActionResult AddUser()
{
    return View();
}
```

There seems to be an AND between the global policy and this so it won't work. If I add [AllowAnonymous] the policy is not evaluated at all.

How can I replace the global policy with a custom policy for one action?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up leaving the global authentication requirement and put AllowAnonymous on  the actions. I then solved the requirement by adding code in the action that checks that the user is either authenticated or that the user db is empty.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/03/15/get-started-with-asp-net-core-authorization-part-1-of-2/ .. this could help

Answer (score 5):

You can't. Policies are additive. So, global will always be there, and then any extra policies are evaluated after. In addition policies require authentication, you can't have a policy that allows unauthenticated users or something else, they must always be authenticated, as authentication acts upon the results of authorization.

Comment: Can you have a policy on the controller and then a different one on the route, thus "overriding" the controller policy?

Comment: @blowdart You stated that "... polices require authentication ... they must always be authenticated, as authentication acts upon the results of authorization".  I'm curious, if `Authorize(Policy="SomePolicy")` always results in an authenticated user what is the purpose of `policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser()`?

Answer (score 4):

You could just remove the global authorization policy, and just authorize at the controller level. If you have a controller labelled with [Authorize] and an action labelled [AllowAnnonymous] (or your own custom policy), then the action specific tag takes precedent.